# display the transaction status from authorize.net

Tags: php, authorize.net

I am developing a web application. There I am using authorize.net for the payment process.
I want to display the status of the error message (like Transaction Status:     Declined (Card declined by issuer - Contact card issuer to determine reason.). I have implemented the following code

```
if ("Ok" != $parsedresponse->messages->resultCode) {
                            $errorMsg = '';
                            foreach ($parsedresponse->messages->message as $msg) {
                             $errorMsg .= htmlspecialchars($msg->text);
                            }
                            }
```

But I need the message like Transaction Status:     Declined (Card declined by issuer - Contact card issuer to determine reason.)

Does any one know this?

Comment: Which API are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You would use this code:

```
$parsedresponse->messages->message->text
```